# How do I create image from binary data BSQ?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, geospatial

I've got a problem. I'm trying create image from binary data which I got from hyperspectral camera. The file which I have is in BSQ uint16 format. From the documentation I found out that images contained in the file (.dat) have a resolution of 1024x1024 and there are 24 images in total. The whole thing is to form a kind of "cube" which I want use in the future to creat multi-layered orthomosaic.

I would also like to add that I am completely new in python but I try to be up to date with everything I need. I hope that everything what I have written is clear and uderstandable.

At first I tried to use Numpy liblary to creating 3D array but ended up with an arrangement of random pixels.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

file=open('Sequence 1_000021.dat','rb')

myarray=np.fromfile(file,dtype=np.uint16)

print('Size of new array',":", len(myarray))

con_array=np.reshape(myarray,(24,1024,1024),'C')

naPIL=Image.fromarray(con_array[1,:,:])
naPIL.save('naPIL.tiff')
```

The result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93G1K.jpg)

Example of image which I want to achieve (thumbnail): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOM3d.png)

Comment: could you provide a link to a file?  failing that, at a guess it might be byte ordering issues (try with `dtype=">u2"`).  you could try with GDAL as it seems to know about these file formats, e.g. https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html

Comment: @SamMason https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UswVEac3mfSC2kEXtxJApZzxjPDdpfS1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just FYI, I believe **BSQ** refers to *"band sequential* which is *"planar"* in more modern, less GIS-speak. **BIP** is *"band interleaved by pixel"* which is maybe more commonly called *"chunky"* or RGB. **BIL** is *"band interleaved by line"*. This stuff is generally referred to as the *"interleave"* setting.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yup, sounds right.  I only really see reference to this via ENVI and ArcGIS. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/bil-bip-and-bsq-raster-files.htm looks like the most complete description I could find.  presumably OP has an associated ASCII "header file" that would describe the format of the binary data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected it's just byte order, I get a sensible looking image when running the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# open as big-endian, convert to native order, then reshape as appropriate
raw = np.fromfile(
  './Sequence 1_000021.dat', dtype='>u2'
).astype('uint16').reshape((24, 1024, 1024))

# display inline
Image.fromarray(raw[1,:,:])
```

Comment: Wow , thank you so much for your help. It works as it should!